# How to export multiple MXDs using Python?

Tags: python, arcpy, export, data-driven-pages

I have several MXDs that use Data-Driven-Pages to create an updated mapbook every month. 15-18 mapbooks and 163 pages each. This usually takes me two days and I'd like to automate this. I can export one with Python, but more than one is stumping me.
I export one using this in Python:

```
map1 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("map1 mxd location")

map1.dataDrivenPages.exportToPDF(r"folder where I want pdf stored", "RANGE", "1-163","PDF_MULTIPLE_FILES_PAGE_NAME")

del map1
```

It works great for one map, but how can I export map1, map2, map3 etc.. to separate folders with one executed command?

Just to be clear, I know I need to specify each MXD and export location individually. What I'm looking to learn is how to enter all that information at once, double tap my enter button and walk away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this looks like a problem where a for-loop would work. If you have a list of your MXDs (including path), you can loop over them.

```
listofmaps = open(r"C:\Users\maplist.txt","r")
for map in listofmaps:
   map1 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(map)
   map1.dataDrivenPages.exportToPDF(r"folder where I want pdf stored", "RANGE",    "1-163","PDF_MULTIPLE_FILES_PAGE_NAME")
   del map1
```

Each map in the text file will be output to the folder.

Comment: Thank you @Sam and everyone else for the replies. I've tried all 3 and this is the first one that worked for me. I'm sure I was doing something wrong with the other two. Here's what I ended up with if anyone is interested.

>>> listofmaps = open(r"C:\Users\....ListofMaps.txt", "r")
>>> for maps in listofmaps:
...     Hse200 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Hse200 mxd location")
...     Hse200.dataDrivenPages.exportToPDF(r"Hse200 PDF destination")
...     del Hse200
...     #repeat for all the maps you need
...     break  (I've learned break is very VERY important)

Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2):

This uses `os.walk` to find all MXDs within a root directory.

It uses `os.path.join` to combine the file path and filename, and creates an output PDF name within the directory the MXD is located.

```
import os
import arcpy

#change to the root of where all the MXDs are stored
workspace = "C:\\Projects"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(workspace):
    for name in filenames:
        if "mxd" in name:
           output_name = str(name.split("mxd")[0]) + "pdf"
           output_path = os.path.join(dirpath, output_name)

           map_document = os.path.join(dirpath, name)

           mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(map_document)
           mxd.dataDrivenPages.exportToPDF(output_path, "ALL", multiple_files="PDF_MULTIPLE_FILES_PAGE_NAME")

           del mxd
```

So, for `C:\\Projects\\Rebuild\\Imagery.mxd` the output is `C:\\Projects\\Rebuild\\Imagery.pdf`

In your example, you have a `RANGE` set. To do this adds a bit more complexity (if it's different for each MXD), and you'll need to reference some file that has this information. In this example, I've set it to `ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a python list and a `for` loop for this.

```
#List all maps here
maps = ["map1 mxd location", 
        "map2 mxd location", 
        "map3 mxd location"]

for map in maps:
    map1 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(map)
    #etc etc
```